# How to create the Scaladoc for a Maven+Scala 2.8+Java-Project with Scaladoc 2

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, scaladoc

The question says it all. I couldn't find an example on the web how to use the Scaladoc 2, especially on a Maven Project.

I'm using Maven, Scala 2.8 and some Java classes, and the Maven Scala Plugin to build the project.
But as it seems i cannot use the Maven Scala Plugin (where i could run mvn scala:doc) to create the docs because it uses VScaladoc - which has [an issue](http://github.com/davidB/vscaladoc/issues#issue/9) on Scala 2.8/Scaladoc 2, resulting in an `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

How can i build the Scaladoc for my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're working on a fix, however I know DavidB and I are very short on free time, so patches are welcome! ;)

My guess (without looking into it) is that we don't have special handling for scaladoc vs. scaladoc2.   The maven-scala-plugin attempts to handle Scala versions 2.6 (and less) -> 2.8 which is a pretty broad range.   I'm guessing the special handling for 2.8+ versions is slightly off..

Comment: Yeah i already chatted with DavidB http://github.com/davidB/vscaladoc/issues#issue/9 (maybe i should have asked that question there). So as i understand the Maven Scala Plugin doesn't support generating Scaladoc for Scala 2.8. But is there a way to generate the Doc without the MavenScala Plugin? Would it THEN be possible? Or is there any workaround until this is fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Since version 2.14.2 of maven-scala-plugin, the plugin use Scaladoc2 for project based on scala 2.8+